# How to repeat argument in String format in Scala

Tags: java, scala, string-formatting

How to reuse the same string for format placement? e.g

```
"%s-%s-%s" format("OK")
>> "OK-OK-OK"
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This should work:

```
"%1$s-%1$s-%1$s" format "OK"
```

The `format` method of [WrappedString](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.WrappedString) uses `java.util.Formatter` under the hood. And the the [Formatter Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) says:

> The format specifiers for general, character, and numeric types have the following syntax:
>
> ```
> %[argument_index$][flags][width][.precision]conversion
> ```
>
> The optional `argument_index` is a decimal integer indicating the position of the argument in the argument list. The first argument is referenced by `"1$"`, the second by `"2$"`, etc.

Answer (score 6):

```
"%s-%s-%s".format(Seq.fill(3)("OK"): _*)
```

The `: _*` part means "use this sequence as the arguments".  `Seq.fill(3)("OK")` creates three copies of `"OK"`.